# XML Serialization No Longer Formatting Correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was able to create an XML serializer in Unity which saves my game state and was working fine. I haven't touched it since then, but a few days later it started saving the XML files on one line instead.

This was how it looked before:

```xml
<GameData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <gameFlags/>
    <memories/>
    <lastSaveTime>-8586819040232916923</lastSaveTime>
    <health>50</health>
    <speed>0.27</speed>
    <playerPosition>
        <x>10</x>
        <y>-48.2583</y>
        <z>0</z>
    </playerPosition>
    <lastSaveFile/>
    <savedScene>Area 0-0</savedScene>
    <playerName>Jon</playerName>
    <PlayerPositionX>10</PlayerPositionX>
    <PlayerPositionY>-48.2583</PlayerPositionY>
    <PlayerPositionZ>0</PlayerPositionZ>
</GameData>
```

This is how it looks now

```
-8586812865931894767 50 0.27 10 -48.2583 0  Default Area 0-0 Jon 10 -48.2583 0
```

Everything is all on one line. I reverted to my previous commit as well when it was working but it still is saving on one line. Does anyone have any experience with this change?

Save Game Method

```
public void SaveGame(string saveFile)
{
    CheckDirectory();

    gameData.generateGameData (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Player>());

    // Update saveFile name
    if (saveFile == null)
    {
        saveFile = GenerateNewSaveName();
    }

    this.saveFile = saveFile;

    // FileStream fs = File.Create(GameDic.Instance.SavePath + saveFile);

    UpdateSaveData(saveFile);

    string fullSavePath = SavePath + saveFile + FILE_EXTENSION;

    FileStream fs;

    // Create a file or open an old one up for writing to
    if (!File.Exists(fullSavePath))
    {
        fs = File.Create(fullSavePath);
    }
    else
    {
        fs = File.OpenWrite(fullSavePath);
    }

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GameData));
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, gameData);
    fs.Close();

    Debug.Log("Game Saved to " + fullSavePath);
}
```

GameData Class

```
[Serializable]
public class GameData
{
    #region Public Fields

    public List<GameFlag> gameFlags;
    public List<string> memories;
    public List<string> conversations;
    public List<QuestInstance> questInstances;

    public long lastSaveTime;
    public float health, speed;

    // Needs properties to access
    [NonSerialized]
    public Vector3 playerPosition;

    public string lastSaveFile;

    public string savedScene;
    public string playerName;

    #endregion Public Fields

    #region Public Constructors


    public void generateGameData(Player player) {
        health = player.getStat (Stat.HP);
        speed = player.getStat (Stat.SPEED);
        savedScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().name;
        playerPosition = player.respawnPoint;
        playerName = "Jon";
        memories = player.GetComponentInChildren<MemoryManager> ().getAccessedMemories ();
        conversations = player.GetComponentInChildren<NPCManager> ().getConversations ();
        questInstances = player.GetComponent<QuestManager> ().getQuestInstances ();
}


    public string GenerateNewSaveName()
    {
        int attempt = 0;
        string newSaveName = "";

        while (newSaveName == "")
        {
        // Save Name is Player Name
            string checkString = gameData.playerName;

        // Add a number if original already taken
            if (attempt != 0) checkString += attempt;

            if (!File.Exists(SavePath + checkString))
            {
            // Make the check string the new file name
                newSaveName = checkString;
            }

            attempt++;
        }

        return newSaveName;
     }


}
```

For the QuestInstance class I suppose it just can just be any filler class that's empty. It's serialized correctly.

Comment: You should include the code that does the actual saving, the classes that are being serialized and anything else you are missing for a [mcve]. (Also, please format your code yourself next time)

Comment: I'll add that all in right now. The issue is that there are a lot of custom classes being serialized so it's hard to replicate it.

Comment: Is the *"how it looks now"* what you see in a browser (they often strip the markup) or the **actual** contents of the file how you see them in a text-editor?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I actually have 2 XMLs (1 from when it worked, 1 from now). The browser displays the XML correctly. The second one is just one line.

Also when I try to deserialize it, it fails. But not on the other file.

Comment: Unrelated but not irrelevant: the `[NonSerialized]` attribute has nothing to do with XML, for XML serialization you need `[XmlIgnore]`, that's why `playerPosition` was in your XML twice (I'm guessing `PlayerPositionX` and the other two were wrapper properties).

Comment: *"The browser displays the XML correctly. The second one is just one line."* How does the second one look if you open it in notepad? (or the text-editor of your choice)

Comment: Oh shoot! It looks fine~I feel like a fool ... I feel tricked by it showing properly on one, and not on the other. As for the [NonSerialized] I actually found that out right after writing that and just never got around to removing that tag haha :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is most likely this line:

```
fs = File.OpenWrite(fullSavePath);
```

If the previous file was longer than the new one, you will still have fragments from the previous save file at the end - that's why you can't deserialize it. Get rid of everything in that `if` condition except for the `File.Create` and it should work.

Comment: Interesting~How would I prevent this from happening?

Comment: @JonNguyen By only using `File.Create` - if it already exists, it will get overwritten automatically, so you can omit the `File.Exists` too.

Comment: You're a godsend. Thank you I was panicking that something had gone horribly wrong.

Comment: @JonNguyen You're welcome. If this answers you question, please click the checkmark in the top left of my answer to mark your question as answered.